# Having the button raise click event even if it is disabled in jquery

Tags: jquery

There are a lot of questions on exactly opposite on what I want to achieve.

I need my  to raise an `.click` attached function even when the button is disabled (disabled attribute set on it).

I need to do this in jQuery 1.7.1 and don't want to hack into it with an errors in deprecated API's.

I know this is kind of "against the rules of logic", but can this be done?

For example the button is disabled and in order to enable it a user needs to check one of the check boxes. I need to shake the title of the check boxes on disabled button click in that case for better user experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest adding a transparent span covering your button in cases where it is disabled, and attaching the the click event to it instead.
As far as I know, it isn't possible to trigger mouse events of a button (using the mouse - it is possible with the trigger method) while it is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Is it ok for you to use the `trigger` method?
If so, take a look at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/X6rzg/

Comment: No he wants to trigger a click event when the user clicks on a disabled button

Comment: I've seen this approach. But from what code would I call $("#btnTest").trigger("click"); ? I don't have a click method =)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking now, you want to know where to place the code that calls the trigger? if so, I'd need to take a look into your code.

Answer (score 0):

managed to get this to work in chrome. this just monoitors mouseout of the form and sees if the target is dsiabled maybe see if you can take it that bit further?

You could bind a click event to the document inside the statement detecting if element is disabled to call the requied function and unbind it when form gets mouseover back from a disabled element.

[simulated hover on disabled element](http://jsfiddle.net/PHPsycho/WcxxG/6/)